# how to do vim paste in shell?

Tags: shell, vim

I used the following command to find `google` in `1.txt` and paste it once, but it didn't work. I guess it's because `p` in vim is not a command using after `:`. But how can I fix this problem?

```
vim "+g/google/y a" -c "p" -c "wq" 1.txt
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `vim` for this, and not i.e. `sed` or `grep`?

Answer (score 2):

[Ex](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:)-command for pasting is [`:put`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:put):

```
-c put
```

(no need to quote, there is nothing to protect from shell.)

You can also use [`:normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal):

```
-c "normal p"
```

(quotes are used to protect the space.)